# jquery ajax success dropdownlist value change but textbox not changing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This is my dropdownlist for the location, and will update another dropdownlist for the price for the particular location

```
$('#my_location').change(function () {
        //updated
        var val = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());

        getDayPrice(val);
    });
```

this is my getDayPrice function

```
function getDayPrice(my_id)
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getvalue.php",
            data: { id: my_id },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#my_duration').empty();
                $('#my_duration').append(data);
                console.log(data);

                $('#txt_my_duration').val(Date.now());
                $('#txt_my_cost').val( Date.now());
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error handing here');
            }
        });
    }
```

The dropdownlist for duration is updated no matter which #my_location. However, the two textbox only updated the first item only.

This is the example of the location

```
<select class="form-control" id="my_location" name="my_location">
<option value="1">My Home</option>
<option value="2">My Office</option>
<option value="3">My Playground</option>
<option value="4">My garage</option>
<option value="5">My Bathroom</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="txt_my_duration" id="txt_my_duration" value="" />
<input type="text" name="txt_my_cost" id="txt_my_cost" value="" />
```

When Initial is select to `My Home` and the price dropdownlist is correct, When I change to `My Office`, the dropdownlist also correct, but the two textbox did not update. When I click back to `My Home`, the price dropdownlist is correct and the textbox is updated.

Why it only work for the first option?

**UPDATE**

If I skip the ajax, the two textbox will update, no matter which dropdownlist I selected.

```
function getDayPrice(my_id)
    {

        data = "<option value="3">My Playground</option>";
                $('#my_duration').empty();
                $('#my_duration').append(data);
                console.log(data);


                var matches = data.match(/value='([^])'/i);
                var content = data.match(/>([^s]+)<\/option>/i);
                console.log(matches[1]);

                console.log(content[1]);
                //$('#txt_my_duration').val(matches[1]);
                //$('#txt_my_cost').val(content[1]);
                $('#txt_my_duration').val(Date.now());
                $('#txt_my_cost').val(Date.now());
    }
```

Attached Console log

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/getvalue.php".send @ jquery.min.js:5
getvalue.php:756 <option value='1'>My Home</option>
getvalue.php:760 1473924849426
getvalue.php:764 1473924849426

XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/getvalue.php".send @ jquery.min.js:5
getvalue.php:756  <option value='2'>My Office</option>
getvalue.php:760 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of nullsuccess @ getvalue.php:760c @ jquery.min.js:3fireWith @ jquery.min.js:3k @ jquery.min.js:5r @ jquery.min.js:5
jquery.min.js:5 

XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/getvalue.php".send @ jquery.min.js:5
getvalue.php:756 <option value='1'>My Home</option>
getvalue.php:760 1473924849436
getvalue.php:764 1473924849436
```

Comment: show the html for the my_duration and txt_my_duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the selected value

```
var val = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
```

note: if you have multiple selects with the same id the value vill be the value of the first select with that id

Assuming that matches is the value of the option and content is the text do the following

```
var matches = $(data).val();
var content = $(data).text();
$('#txt_my_duration').val(matches);
$('#txt_my_cost').val(content);
```

Comment: Can't we use `$(this).val()`?

Comment: my life is not working, your comment is not working for me, what do you mean by not working? are there any console errors?

Comment: @madalin, my textbox is displayed current time. It should be updated when I click the event.

Comment: are the inputs added by ajax?

Comment: I updated the console log. When I select other than 1, the textbox datetime value won't update. But the dropdownlist load will update from ajax.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null what is this ?

Comment: Sorry, I want to testing so I put Date.now(), my goal is want to get the value and the name from the ajax output. let me update more in the questions. so sorry for that.

Comment: @madalinivascu I had updated, the error because of the regular expression. But it also due to no value catch from the data response from the success

Comment: I just inspect to the code, I found the when I select other than the first value, the match variable will return null. Is it due to ajax asynchronous cannot update the match variable?

Comment: what match variable ?

Comment: It is matches variable; var matches = data.match(/value='([^])'/i); I updated in the questions. When I inspect matches.

Comment: what are you trying to do with those regexes?

Comment: want to get the value of the id, and the content of the option and remove the word "My ", I just need  "Home"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123464/discussion-between-shiro-and-madalin-ivascu).

Comment: the last part of my answer may help you

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issu is you are loading the options dynamically to the dropdown. If so, you have to use `onchane`

```
$('body').on('change', '#my_location', function () {
     // Do your stuff
}
```